# How do you collect timer string data in object

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop

I have a simple count-up timer that displays milliseconds, seconds, and minutes in real time. When a certain condition is met the stop timer is triggered. I am confused on how to get that time stored in an object and then displayed by shortest time first.

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(100);
timer.start();
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTickHandler);
var timerCount:int = 0;

function timerTickHandler(Event:TimerEvent):void
{
    timerCount += 100;
    toTimeCode(timerCount);
}

function toTimeCode(milliseconds:int) : void 
{
//creating a date object using the elapsed milliseconds
var time:Date = new Date(milliseconds);

//define minutes/seconds/mseconds
var minutes:String = String(time.minutes);
var seconds:String = String(time.seconds);
var miliseconds:String = String(Math.round(time.milliseconds)/100);

//add zero if neccecary, for example: 2:3.5 becomes 02:03.5
minutes = (minutes.length != 2) ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
seconds = (seconds.length != 2) ? '0'+seconds : seconds;

//display elapsed time on in a textfield on stage
timer_txt.text = minutes + ":" + seconds+"." + miliseconds;
}
```

I also have a button if the button is clicked it sets a boolean to true.

```
var btn1:Button;
var buttonClckd:Boolean;

if (buttonClckd == true) {
            timer.stop();
            timeTxt.type = myUsers.userTime;
            trace(myUsers.userTime);
            trace("Btn1 Click == true");
        }


btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn1Clicked);



public function btn1Clickd(e: MouseEvent):void {
        trace("btn1 Clicked");
        buttonClckd = true;


    }
```

Unfortunately, I don't get the trace of "Btn1 Click == true"

Comment: First - read the guidelines how to ask a question! **Post some code!** What do you mean by shortest time? You have different variables for all the properties that you increment, or what?

Comment: Shortest time is the fastest time being at the top of the list.

Comment: So now you've got `Date` object. What's your actual question - I don't see any kind of list nor multiple `Date` objects..?

Comment: That is what I am asking... I just need the time at the point of the timer stop stored in an object or array. I don't know how to build that array.

Comment: Well you have the `Date` object!

Comment: My custom object is myUser.time. I need the minutes, seconds, and milliseconds stored in that myUser.time object. Is that possible? If so what is the best way to go about doing that? Is it as simple as timer_txt.text = myUser.time?

Comment: Your system is very inaccurate. Timer instances are not meant to keep track of time so whatever time your system comes up with is false right at the start and will keep getting worse at time passes on. Only by using a Date instance you can come up with an accurate timing system.

Comment: I am using a Date instance... The only other getTimer(); I tried that but I don't see real time results like this one.

Comment: You are not using Date to keep track of time, your system produces time that is very inaccurate even after 2, 3 seconds. You can set a Timer to 100 as you do but that Timer will trigger at random times like 93, 106, 134, etc ... So adding 100 to your timerCount is in term of time already wrong after the first timer event.

Answer (score 0):

The main idea:

```
var startingDate:Date;
var compareDate:Date;
var startingTime:uint;
var compareTime:uint;
```

When you start your game you init those variables (in a start function for example):

```
startingDate = new Date();
compareDate = new Date();
compareDate.time = startingDate.time;
startingTime = getTimer();
compareTime = 0;
```

Now you start an enterframe or timer and reset your time:

```
compareTime = getTimer() - startingTime;
compareDate.time = startingDate.time + compareTime;
var elapsedTime:uint = compareDate.time - startingDate.time;
```

The elapsedTime now holds to correct time.

If you want to pause:

```
var pauseStart:uint;
```

in pause function:

```
pauseStart = getTimer();
```

in resume function:

```
startingTime += getTimer() - pauseStart;
startingDate.time += getTimer() - pauseStart;
```

Now you get an accurate time system with elapsedTime giving you the correct time at all time since you started.

As to your question, all you need to store is the milliseconds so in this case the elapsedTime, the shorter one is the shortest time.

Comment: by shortest I mean the user finishing the fastest.

Comment: by shortest I mean the user finishing the fastest. The object is going to be added or written to an XML db. ... And I don't know how to go from what you have to what I had, as a real time display of a timer. Sorry I am kinda confused now. To rephrase everything and to offer more explanation: The timer is started at the point they enter the area. To move on they have to press a series of buttons. Then I have to stop the time at the end of the button click series if done correctly.  So after the timer is stopped, the time recorded written to the xml, the score shown.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Date.UTC()` function to turn your `Date` object into a `Number`, which you can easily compare and select the object that has less elapsed time.

And, in your case, using `Date` is overkill, as you already have those milliseconds from which you should directly derive seconds and minutes. Also comparing milliseconds as they are is a  lot easier than comparing `Date` objects.

```
function toTimeCode(milliseconds:Number) : void 
{
    var se:Number=Math.floor(milliseconds/1000);
    var mi:Number=Math.floor(se/60);
    var ms:Number=Math.floor(milliseconds-1000*se);
    se=se-mi*60;
    // rest of translations remain intact
    var minutes:String = mi.toFixed(0);
    var seconds:String = se.toFixed(0);
    var miliseconds:String = String(ms/100);

    //add zero if neccecary, for example: 2:3.5 becomes 02:03.5
    minutes = (minutes.length != 2) ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds.length != 2) ? '0'+seconds : seconds;
    //display elapsed time on in a textfield on stage
    timer_txt.text = minutes + ":" + seconds+"." + miliseconds;
}
```

And finally, in order to compare current or final milliseconds you have to store the topmost value (or a list of them, you've said you have one) somewhere, and then just walk through that set, stuffing the current value into the array in the proper position.

Comment: I don't need a number. Couldn't I utilize the populated strings. I just need that string in my object at the point the condition is met..

Comment: In this case you should store both a string and a number. Working with numbers is a lot easier than with strings in terms of numeric comparison. Do you know that `trace("111"<"12")` returns true? In your case, the discrepancies will start at 100 minutes vs 11, so direct comparison is out of question.

Comment: cannot disagree more with the answer as the PO system is already inaccurate to start with. Timer are not meant to keep track of time and they are very bad at it. At the minimum they should be corrected using getTimer() but using the Date class is really the best and most accurate way to keep track of time.

Comment: @BotMaster Given that OP uses `new Date(milliseconds)` he is already using the date objects wrongly. I myself would measure time in frames, not in seconds, because frames are uniform in terms of display vs reaction, one frame per one choice of reaction, and I have seen many games which depend on timers or `getTimer()` results in an enterframe handler that, if lagged a bit, proved unplayable due to a sudden game over situation after a single displayed frame.

Comment: While calling `new Date()` at the start *and the end* of a given exercise will most likely provide the most accurate results of the time spent during the exercise, I'd still not use this to implement a clock that displays elapsed time in real time, due to optional pausing that is largely required to be provided to the player. With frames you can easily get the game state and only increment the counter if the exercise is paused.

Comment: Can you form a figurative answer so that I may update my code. I would greatly appreciate it. Secondly, I am not using frames, only time. There is only one frame in my .fla file.

Comment: There's 2 accurate time system, Date and getTimer(). Use Date to keep track of time and display it. Use getTimer() to account for any pause. Used together you can get a time system that is very accurate especially for game. Any other system like the one you describe will end up being inaccurate and provide only a guessed time at best.

Comment: @SunRhythms - the frames referenced are the frame rate of the application.  You can have code run every frame tick - it's irrespective of any timeline frames you may or may not have in Flash Professional.

Comment: Could you tell me how to push the correct data/string to the myUsers.userTime object?

Comment: @BotMaster There are two different things, "elapsed time" and "leveraged elapsed time", both are needed in some situations. When you are organizing a competition, aka a game, the factor of device used for competing is prevalent, and if a user has a device that's slower than "average", that user is apriori out of the lead and out of chances to get leadership if "elapsed time" is not leveraged. IMO frame-based "elapsed time" is better leveraged against different devices than `Date` and `getTimer()` approach.

Comment: There was a game named "Pyro" which used system time (either `Date` or `getTimer()`) to account for best time on the level, and frame-based evolution of the puzzle to display/trace if it is solved, but it had a fire special effect that was dragging the performance of the simulation down, therefore the desired "par" times on levels could not be achieved if a user's device is slower than a certain level. This, and several of the other games like that, strongly encourage me to propagate the idea of leveraged (frame-based) elapsed time to equalize players regardless of their devices.

Comment: If a game animation/motion is not time based then all time recorded are flawed no matter what time system you use.

Comment: @BotMaster If you equalize animations/motions with time units then "elapsed frames" metric is accurate by default. Some games don't equalize in-game time with frames, though, there real time capturing is more accurate than frame-based time measurement.